# How can i pass subfolder of S3 bucket in Java Program of Amzon Rekognition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

Here is demo Program

```
public class AddFacesToCollection {
public static final String collectionId = "MyCollection";
public static final String bucket = "bucket";
public static final String photo = "input.jpg";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.defaultClient();

    Image image = new Image()
            .withS3Object(new S3Object()
            .withBucket(bucket)
            .withName(photo));
    
    IndexFacesRequest indexFacesRequest = new IndexFacesRequest()
            .withImage(image)
            .withQualityFilter(QualityFilter.AUTO)
            .withMaxFaces(1)
            .withCollectionId(collectionId)
            .withExternalImageId(photo)
            .withDetectionAttributes("DEFAULT");

    IndexFacesResult indexFacesResult = rekognitionClient.indexFaces(indexFacesRequest);
    
    System.out.println("Results for " + photo);
```

I want to add the images of subfolder of bucket like bucketName/image/image1.jpg . How can i do that in java.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to call `indexFaces()` while passing multiple images? This is not possible. The `indexFaces()` API call only accepts a single image. You would need to loop through each image, and call `indexFaces()` for each one.

Comment: No I am not asking about indexFaces().I just want to pass single image but that image is inside of subfolder of my S3 bucket. For example my bucket name is "demo". Inside my bucket I have another folder "image" and inside image folder only single image image1.jpg. now I want to set my bucket name like "demo/image". But I got error. So how can I set my bucket name like "bucketname/subfoldername".

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

- `Bucket=demo`
- `Key=subfoldername/image1.jpg`

That is, the path is part of the object name, not the bucket name.

From your code:

```
.withBucket('demo')
.withName('subfoldername/image1.jpg'));
```

Comment: can you send me code example. It will be very helpfull